# Hotel bill dispute

Tags: hotels, disputes

I booked a hotel room in the Netherlands for 2 nights. The hotel was a pay-at-the-property hotel, and didn't need credit card details. Before I arrived I added an extra day over the phone. Upon arrival the owner told me that on the third night I would be getting a bigger room, but he didn't mention anything about the price.

On the day of the room change I asked the man and a woman at the front desk if there were any smaller rooms available in case someone had cancelled, but they told me I would not be getting charged extra for the extra night after checking the system.

It was strange but during checkout the next day, the woman at the front desk confirmed with me that I had stayed in a small room for 2 nights and an extra night in a big room and gave me the final bill, which I payed for.

One week later, I received an email with an invoice for the final night (150 Euros). I am unsure if I should be paying this extra bill after confirming my bill with 3 different employees throughout my stay and never being told about an extra bill until now.

Comment: What does the final bill you were given at check out say? Does it reflect that you paid for all three nights?

Comment: @ZachLipton its in dutch so I cant even read it

Comment: So what does Google translate indicate your bill says?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas it says that I stayed there for 3 nights but it has the prices for 2 nights. Which goes along with what one of the employees said when they told me that I was not going to be charged

Comment: I'm a little unclear. It seems strange that they would give you the third night completely for free. I've never heard of a hotel giving a free night absent some reason (customer loyalty, something was wrong with your stay and they comped a night by way of apology, etc...). Is it possible that they meant that there would be no additional charge for the larger room (because you wanted a small one and all they had was a large one) and that you would just pay the ordinary cost of a small room for another night?

Comment: How much were the first two nights?  150 Euro each, or less?

Comment: @Doc it was 198 euros for the first 2 nights

Comment: @ZachLipton yeah its strange but their english was perfect so it wasnt a language barrier. Even then they want me to pay for the full price of the big room. Every person I talked to said the same thing and this invoice contradicts all of them which is frustrating

Comment: I also assume they ment they would not charge extra (so 99 for the extra night not 150). If you post a scan of the bill, someone here could translate it (me for instance).

Comment: Did you ask for the price for a third night when booking? 150€ could very well be the regular price for the smaller room for the third night. The price could be higher because you booked on a shorter notice, the hotel may operate with different prices on different weekdays, during events or for many other reasons.